# PHP: Searching a string for all sub strings in an array AND THEN echo any matches?

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

```
$longString = "I walk in the park.";
$stringArray = array("walk", "park", "beach");
```

Basically, I want to search `$longString` for all sub strings that are in the `$stringArray`. So in this case, I would like to find walk and park and then echo those strings.

Is this doable? Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, it's doable. What have you tried? Because SO !== *"write my code for me k thanks!"*

Comment: You have a syntax error. `array()` not `array{)`. Also, the trailing comma can go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the array and check if that string is present in the long string:

```
$longString = "I walk in the park and I like to jumprope.";
$stringArray = array("walk" => "walk", "park" => "park", "jumprope" => "jump rope");

foreach( $stringArray as $search => $print) {
    if( !(strpos( $longString, $search) === false)) {
        echo $print;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/HtQ9mGeV)

Comment: You could additionally/optionally `lcase()` both the `$longString` and `$stringArray` to match without sensitivity to case.

Comment: Correct, or change out the call to `strpos` for `stripos` for case insensitivity.

Comment: It's incorrect, because strpos can return 0 index if substring on the beginning of the string, better use !== false operator.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko: He did. He used `===` and then negated the whole thing. Same thing as `!==`.

Comment: quick question. 
why !(code) === false , instead of (code) == true?

Comment: I prefer to use !( x === false), instead of ( x !== true). It correlates better with the documentation, but it's just my preference.

Comment: For the sake of correctness, `!(x === false)` is not the same as `(x !== true)`. Those are opposites. If `x` is `false`, the first will ultimately return `false`, while the second will return `true`. Think you meant `(x !== false)`. And @jugzor, in case you aren't familiar with the `===` syntax, look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). If the substring is found at index 0, then 0 is returned. The integer 0 converts to boolean `false`, so with a loose comparison, even though the string was found, you would get `false`.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake - Yes, I meant `(x !== false)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$longString = "I walk in the park.";
$stringArray = array("walk", "park", "beach");

foreach ($stringArray as $item) {
    if (stristr($longString, $item))
        echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify, but this method also matches "parked" or "beached" ... regex is required if word boundaries are important.

Answer (score 0):

```
$longString = "I walk in the park.";
$stringArray = array{"walk", "park", "beach",);

foreach( $stringArray as $search) {
    if(strpos( $longString, $search) !== FALSE) {
        echo $search;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify, but this method also matches "parked" or "beached" ... regex is required if word boundaries are important.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible:

```
$longString  = "I walk in the park.";
$stringArray = array("walk", "park", "beach");

foreach ($stringArray as $key => $val) {
    if (strpos($longString, $val) === false) {
        unset($stringArray[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($stringArray);
```

`$stringArray` will contain only the strings which appear in `$longString`.